# Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl

Não consigo utilizar o `ServiceReference` após importação com sucesso.
Após executar a importação, escrever a classe e utilizar seus métodos na compilação ocorrem os Warnings:

### Warning 1

```
Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.
Parameter name: name
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sigiss_ws']/wsdl:portType[@name='WebService SigISSPortType']    C:\ProjetosVS\ClientWBAws\ClientWBAws\ClientWBAws\Service References\ServiceReferenceSigISS\Reference.svcmap    1   1   ClientWBAws
```

### Warning 2

```
Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sigiss_ws']/wsdl:portType[@name='WebService SigISSPortType']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sigiss_ws']/wsdl:binding[@name='WebService SigISSBinding']  C:\ProjetosVS\ClientWBAws\ClientWBAws\ClientWBAws\Service References\ServiceReferenceSigISS\Reference.svcmap    1   1   ClientWBAws
```

### Warning 3

```
Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sigiss_ws']/wsdl:binding[@name='WebService SigISSBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sigiss_ws']/wsdl:service[@name='WebService SigISS']/wsdl:port[@name='WebService SigISSPort']    C:\ProjetosVS\ClientWBAws\ClientWBAws\ClientWBAws\Service References\ServiceReferenceSigISS\Reference.svcmap    1   1   ClientWBAws
```

### Erro:

```
Error   4   Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'ServiceReferenceSigISS'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.  C:\ProjetosVS\ClientWBAws\ClientWBAws\ClientWBAws\Service References\ServiceReferenceSigISS\Reference.svcmap    1   1   ClientWBAws
```

O devo fazer para corrigir esse problema?

Comment: Você consegue fazer as chamadas funcionarem com o `WCFTestClient.exe`?

Answer (score 3):

Sem o arquivo que você importou eu não consigo dar a solução completa para o seu problema, mas posso te ajudar a explicar os avisos.

Warning 1: diz que não vai poder importar o wsdl:port pois existe um ' ' ( espaço em branco ) no nome do tipo, o que não pode existir.

Warnings 2, 3 e 4 são consequencias do primeiro. O 2 e 3 dizem que os tipos declarados dependem o tipo do Warning 1 que não foi possível ser formado, desta forma este últimos também não podem. Finalmente o Warning 4 que o Build falhou a executar e que você deve ver os erros/avisos acima.

Resumindo: retire o espaço do nome do tipo que você tem grandes chances de se livrar de todos estes avisos.

Answer (score 0):

Como Raul mencionou, a primeira Warning trate-se de um ' ' (espaço) que se encontra num parametro chamado "nome".

Olhando as outras detalhes nas mensagens, destaque-se este trecho:

```
/wsdl:portType[@name='WebService SigISSPortType']
```

Não sei se você consegue mudar o `<wsdl:portType>` e colocar o nome sem espaço:

```xml
<wsdl:portType name="WebService-SigISSPortTYpe" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido. O problema estava na forma que eu declarava a classe.

Comment: Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer quem te ajudou é assinalando a melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil pra todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.

Comment: Seria bom descrever como estava a classe e como foi corrigido, para que outros também possam evitar o mesmo problema.